# Subversion using in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I come from a Microsoft background in coding and thus have been used to Team Foundation Server and such for source control.  Under TFS the files would check out by themselves in Eclipse and I would check them in when I was finished.

I have installed Subversion and the connector into Eclipse and have created my project with a local server

On Subversion do I have to check out the file when I need to change it?  It doesnt change the RW permissions so I am not sure what the procedure is.

So basically if I am using Subversion in Eclipse what is the procedure for checking out a file and checking it in?  What buttons are clicked?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I would checkout the entire project, make my changes and then use the team sync view to review my code changes and commit from there.  Right clicking is the key (see screenshots)

[image: activate eclipse team synchronize perspective]

[image: eclipse commit from team synchronize perspective]

Comment: Side question: how did you get the black background on eclipse with diff colors on the reserved words? Thanks (ref Reporter.java img)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to "check out" to enable editing a file in Subversion. Subversion does not use the same type of locking VSS does (and TFS, by the sound of it - though I haven't used TFS myself). The locking that svn uses is sometimes called optimistic locking. Here is the [svn manual page on file sharing and locking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.vsn-models.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.problem-sharing) with a lot more specific details.

In Subversion, you would update your working copy like you normally would, but without any additional steps you could then just begin performing your changes to any file in the working copy without needing to lock out any other users, and commit when ready. If no one has modified it since you updated, then it will just commit the changes. Even if someone has, it will still commit (provided the same lines were not modified) and the server will handle it. If however, someone else modified the same lines of the file as you, then a conflict would occur and the commit would fail with "one or more files are in conflict". The conflict must then be manually looked at, eliminated, and marked as resolved, after which you would retry the commit and it would then go through (provided nothing else was in conflict).

Conflicts during every day work on a single branch are rare, which is why a lot of versioning systems use optimistic locking. Only when dealing with merging back and forth between branches do things sometimes get more involved.

Answer (score 0):

A great walk through on the basics can be viewed [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/).

Most of your actions will reside on under the `Team` menu; where you can commit, add, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I use to use Subversion with eclipse.  Now I use subversion with VSS.  In both situations I've found I prefer, most of the time, to use Tortoise SVN for all my operations with the repository.  Not as much of an answer but more of an opinion.